# Android Studio 3.0 Unsigned Apk Not Installing

Tags: android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

After upgrading to android studio 3.0 the debug apk is saying **App not istalled.**

> The package appears to be corrupted

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like we can not directly use the apk after running on the device from the build->output->apk folder.

> After upgrading to android studio 3.0 you need to go to **Build -> Build
>   Apk(s)** then copy the apk from build -> output -> apk -> debug

**Like this -**

[image]

Comment: This worked. But why? What does "build apk(s)" do that clicking the debug icon to build and run didn't do?

Comment: App not installed while updating to Android - P, Same error while trying above solution with both debug and release apk's.Can you please help me on this ?Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @naveen try to follow the steps that I mentioned it should work. Otger wise go to project view -》 app -》 build -》 output - 》 apk. You should find your apk here.

Comment: Hi Anirban, Thanks for your response. I have tried above solution you mentioned but didn't worked out.Can you please help me?

Comment: Then `signingConfigs` are not used anymore? Because I understand that if we can't install the apks in build->output->apk  is because they are not signed.

Answer (score 3):

Fist Click On Build Icon on android studio after that click Build APK(s)
then Generate APK the copy Apk.
It is working perfact.

Answer (score 1):

File-> Invalidate Caches/restart

solve problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a signed APK for it to install correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem after upgrading android studio to version 3.0!
To solve this issue you need to ***disable instant run*** that can be found under 
**File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run**. Now You need to re-generate a signed apk with both the signature versions enabled i.e V1 & V2 that can be found under **Build -> Generate Signed APK** Now try to install the signed apk, this time it should be installed perfectly :).

Answer (score 0):

So the message "App Not Installed" will refer to multiple causes, and please returning to Android Studio 2.3. from 3.0 is not an option at all!

When we upgrade from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.0 we can find some configuration issues caused mainly by the support libraries, that will cause that our application could not be installed.

To avoid this problem we need to invalidate cache in Android Studio 3.0+ and the problem will be solved.

So File -> invalidate cache and restart

This one is solution that worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Android Studio (4.1.1) just rebuild the project. (Build>Rebuild Project).
Then get you apk at AndroidStudioProjects<Project Name>\app\build\outputs\apk\debug.

Hope it'll work!

Answer (score -1):

first clean your project.
delete old apk and json file in debug folder.
then re generate build apk.
it works.