# App not installed when upgraded to Android - P

Tags: android

App is installing while connecting via USB to mobile, but while sending `.apk` file to others it saying "App not Installed" (both debug and release).

1.[How to overcome app not installed error when building from Android Studio 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035090/how-to-overcome-app-not-installed-error-when-building-from-android-studio-3-0)

2.[Cannot install signed apk to device manually, got error "App not installed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265897/cannot-install-signed-apk-to-device-manually-got-error-app-not-installed)

3.[Android Studio 3.0 Unsigned Apk Not Installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392610/android-studio-3-0-unsigned-apk-not-installing)

Comment: have you uninstalled app for all users?

Comment: yes and then I build again and I was trying to install but "App not installed" error.Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: your app is not uninstalled completely that's why you getting this error. so uninstall your app properly from setting

Comment: I have installed my app in new mobile still getting the same error "App not installed"

Comment: Refer this link for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55489016/452487

Answer (score 2):

While `Android-P` is still preview, I think it sets `testOnly` flag. 
To override it add 
`android.injected.testOnly=false` in `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the Instant Run feature in Android Studio. This feature many times causes troubles in installing apps in other phones.

Check this link to disable Instant run:

[How to disable Instant Run for Android Studio 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999669/how-to-disable-instant-run-for-android-studio-3-0/46999705)

Comment: Hi Nitesh, Thanks for your response, I have tried above solution which you mentioned but didn't worked out.Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Check whether the MinSDK version in build.gradle file is compatible with the phone in which its not installing

Comment: And also try this: Build -> Clean Project and then Rebuild project

Comment: Hi Nitesh, Can you please help me on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49249713/cannot-able-to-build-the-project-after-upgrading-to-android-p

Comment: No not yet...Still same error "App Not Installed" while .apk file to others.

Comment: Try installing the app through USB on other device and then check